# Member-function templates and overloading operator() in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

The following code snippet works for me:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template <class T> T& get () { ... }
};

Foo foo;
foo.get<int>() = ...;
```

However, the following code snippet does not work for me:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template <class T> T& operator() () { ... }
};

Foo foo;
foo<int>() = ...;
```

The errors being:

```
expected primary-expression before '>' token
expected primary expression before ')' token
```

Both errors refer to the `foo<int>()`

Why does this not work and is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Your template `operator()` is pretty unusable, since its instantiations would overload on return value only.  Keep using the `get` name or similar.

Comment: It's not unusable (though it may not be preferable). See the answers below.

Comment: Why are you templatizing the functions but not the class as a whole?

Comment: @Zac, because I don't need to. I'm using this for an entity system kind of thing, so that I can do soemthing like this: `Entity entity = entitySystem.createEntity(); entitySystem.addTrait(entity, Position::id()); ... std::cout << entity.get<Position>().x;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to explicitly specify the template argument, you would need to use the `operator` syntax:

```
foo.operator()<int>()
```

There isn't any way to specify the arguments using the function-call syntax.  If you can't deduce the template arguments from the arguments to the function, it's better to use a member function than an operator overload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your template parameter list is in the wrong place; it's as if you're trying to use an object or function called `foo` with template argument `int`, but in fact it's the `operator()` that you want the template parameter list on.

Unfortunately (arguably so, at least), there is no way around this with operators. You have to call them as full functions:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template <class T> T& operator()() { ... }
};

Foo foo;
foo.operator()<int> = ...;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you could do this

```
class Foo {
public:
  template <class T> operator T&() { ... }
};
```

Then it will automatically call the right function depending on the "return" type:

```
Foo foo;
int i=foo;
```

I know that most people don't like this as the function that's being called depends on the return type, but I find it a great "trick" that often cleans up syntax.

Comment: Extra warning: It will be easy to accidentally instantiate that "conversion" method with an unintended type.

Comment: I think this is a trick that inordinately complicates code. You have provided a conversion operator for *any* type... it's going to hit you in the most unlikely of places where you may neither expect nor even realise it!